# WPF DataGrid binding

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi all i am new to WPF and i have a small problem ,i hope you can help me.

I have a DataGrid in a parent window..when i open a pop up window and select an item,that pop up window closes and the DataGrid in the parent window updated with the selected item.

My problem is when i set the DataGrid's ItemSource property,it works only in the first time,but when i add other items and set the DataGrid's ItemSource it does not update the Grid though the List it is bound to,is updated.

I wonder if there is a method for DataBind() like the ASP.Net GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of *List* are you using?

It ought to work as you described when using  an ObservableCollection.

Comment: I use the Generic List
List<ItemToBeSold>

Comment: @Khaled: then that is the problem. `List<>` does not support notification and will only allow OneShot binding.

Comment: thanks for the help.but what kind of collections should i bind to?

Comment: @Khaled: Use an `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` . You'll have to replace the List or Copy the items at an opportune moment.

Answer (score 2):

In WPF your class typically needs to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).  This interface exposes the PropertyChanged event, which 'notifies' when a property has changed.

Here's an example from [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx)

```
// Declare the PropertyChanged event
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

// OnPropertyChanged will raise the PropertyChanged event passing the
// source property that is being updated.
private void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, string propertyName)
{
    if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(sender, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

You typically call a method like this inside the setter for a binding property.

You can use an ObservableCollection, as Henk suggests, because the ObservableCollection implements this interface and has built in notification on changes (add, remove, etc).  Note that creating a new ObservableCollection won't raise a notification

```
this.BindingCollection = new ObservableCollection(myList);
```

so you will have to raise the notification yourself

```
OnPropertyChanged(this, "BindingCollection");
```